# XML Index Slows Down Queries

Tags: sql-server, xml, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have a simple table with the following structure, with ~10 million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataPoints](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [ModuleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateAndTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Payload] [xml] NULL
)
```

Payload is similar to this for all rows:

```
<payload>
  <total>1000000</total>
  <free>300000</free>
</payload>
```

The following two queries take around 11 seconds each to execute on my dev machine before creating an index on `Payload` column:

```
SELECT AVG(Payload.value('(/payload/total)[1]','bigint')) FROM DataPoints

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DataPoints
WHERE Payload.value('(/payload/total)[1]','bigint') = 1000000
```

The problem is when I create an XML index on `Payload` column, both queries take much longer to complete! I want to know:

1) Why is this happening? Isn't an XML index supposed to speed up queries , or at least a query where a value from the XML column is used in WHERE clause?

2) What would be the proper scenario for using XML indexes, if they are not suitable for my case?

This is on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: What type of XML Indexes are you using? Only a Primary XML Index or also Selective ones? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670108(v=sql.120).aspx "The main limitation with ordinary XML indexes is that they index the entire XML document. This leads to several significant drawbacks, such as decreased query performance and increased index maintenance cost, mostly related to the storage costs of the index."

Comment: Only an ordinary XML index.

Comment: A while ago I placed a question about XML indexes and strange performance: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663 Put in one sentence: Don't use XML indexes, unless you really query your XML **only** in the way where an XML index speeds things up. If you need this more often I'd rather read the data out into a "normal" indexed table...

Comment: What is "the way where an XML index speeds things up"? That is my original question.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy, According to the question mentioned only the `.exist()` method could really speed up and only in case the full path was given (in your example `/payload/total` but not `//total`). The problem is, that in case an index exists it will be used in any case. Even if it is of no help or makes things even worse. I would not use this feature. I'd rather create my own index-like side table...

Answer (score 0):

A ordinary XML Index indexes everything in the XML Payload

> **[Selective XML Indexes (SXI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670108(v=sql.120).aspx)**
>
> The main limitation with ordinary XML indexes is that they index the entire XML document. This leads to several significant drawbacks, such as decreased query performance and increased index maintenance cost, mostly related to the storage costs of the index.

You will want to create a Selective XML index for better performance.

The other option is to create Secondary Indexes

[XML Indexes (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> To enhance search performance, you can create secondary XML indexes. A primary XML index must first exist before you can create secondary indexes.

So the purpose of the Primary Index is so you can create the secondary indexes

Comment: Then what is an ordinary XML "index" useful for? Why is slowing down queries?

Comment: Updated with why you would want an XML Index

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf, you might want to read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663